# Is there a way to Set-ADUser street address the same as the OU address?

Tags: powershell

Title basically says it all.  In our scipt to create users I want to also be able to set the user to the address we have on file for the OU.  Currently we take user input on the form and it's caused a bit of a mess that now needs cleaned up.

Comment: You want to always take it from the immediate parent OU, or you want to "inherit" the street address for users who might be nested _anywhere_ under a specific set of OUs?

Comment: I want to take from the immediate parent OU.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
$user = Get-ADUser SomeUserId
$StreetAddress = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit ($user.DistinguishedName -replace '^.*?(?=OU=|DC=)') -Properties StreetAddress |
    Select-Object -Expand StreetAddress
$user | Set-ADUser -StreetAddress $StreetAddress
```

You can derive the user's OU from the `DistinguishedName` property by removing the `CN=Name` part of the value. `^.*?(?=OU=|DC=)` matches the beginning (`^`) of the string and all characters until just before the first `OU=` or `DC=`. `(?=)` is a positive lookahead and simply peeks ahead from the current position. If the lookahead condition is true, then the matching continues. Those matched characters are removed from the output by the `-replace` operator.